# SQL for getting data from linked tables if sum of data is above certain number

Tags: mysql

I have some sort of evaluating application in the making, it's almost finished but I'm stuck with rather complicated SQL query.

To start with here are linked tables I am using (MySQL):

**table1: USERS (list of users)**

userID | name | surname | email

---

**table2: EVENT (list of events)**

eventID | **event_typeID** | event_name | event_description

---

**table3: EVENT_TYPE  (list of event types, each has number of points that a person gets if it's involved in it)**

event_typeID | number_of_point

---

**table4: USER_EVENT (list of user and event ID's with multiplication factor)**

user_eventID | userID | eventID | factor

---

Function to get needed data is, let's say: **function getUsersWithPoints($number_of_points_for_threshold)**

---

What it needs to do is get name, surname, emailn total sum of points and all EVENTs user has been to for all users which have total number of points in events equal or greater than $number_of_points_for_threshold, but data must be taken indirectly, without getting it in another table.

Thanks in advance.

---

Comment: I don't quite understand your question sir.

The solution is after double horizontal rule :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I'm assuming that USER_EVENT has the event_typeID as a column. I can't where event_typeID is referenced anywhere else. Try something like this:

```
SELECT name, surname, email, sum(number_of_point) 
FROM user, user_event, event_type 
WHERE user.userID = user_event.userID AND user_event.event_typeID = event_type.event_typeID 
GROUP BY user.userID
HAVING sum(number_of_point) > :threshold
ORDER BY name ASC
```

Make sure you have indexes on user_event.userID and user_event.event_typeID a

Comment: Thank you Andy, I have edited the question (since I cannot answer myself yet), I forgot to add one column to one table, but you helped me. Thanks!

Comment: @user1433959: this doesn't take into account "multiplication factor" (number of each event per user, i assume), take a look at my answer for a real solution...

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve the problem I think is to store a running total of points for each user in a table (it could be your users table here). Any time you have an event, you should update the total points for that user.

Comment: The problem is, this is not the solution. Application must work in such a way that next year when I will use the "new year option" and all data stored this year will be outdated (i don't want to lose data from this year, so it has to stay). Events have column with date in it, but since it's not relevant for the problem, I haven't put it here. :)

Maybe creating another table with userID and POINT columns, but still I need to get data in there, plus it doesn't get updated automatically unless I change my functions. But I already have data inside the table(s)

Comment: you can populate the table by summing the points for each of your users in the users table through a query or external code one time and then moving forward you would always update the table on each event. You would be selecting rows from one table as opposed to performing joins every time you want to get data.

Answer (score 0):

Not complicated at all, just use this:

```
SELECT name, surname, email, SUM(sum_points) AS total_points
FROM (SELECT userID, (SUM(factor) * number_of_point) AS sum_points
      FROM USER_EVENT AS ue INNER JOIN EVENT AS e ON ue.eventID = e.eventID
      INNER JOIN EVENT_TYPE AS et ON e.event_typeID = et.event_typeID
      GROUP BY userID, event_typeID, number_of_point) AS sub
INNER JOIN USERS AS u ON sub.userID = u.userID
GROUP BY u.userID, name, surname, email
HAVING total_points >= $number_of_points_for_threshold
```

**UPDATE:** first off, this query takes into account how many of each events user has (not just how many distinct events he has), and secondly, how do you expect to accomplish that, you would need to concatenate all the names (and separately all the descriptions too) together - just use a different query for that:

```
SELECT e.event_name, e.event_description, ue.factor, (ue.factor * et.number_of_point) AS sum_points
FROM USER_EVENT AS ue INNER JOIN EVENT AS e ON ue.eventID = e.eventID
INNER JOIN EVENT_TYPE AS et ON e.event_typeID = et.event_typeID
WHERE ue.userId = @userId
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, this also works. Never the less, I have edited the question, the real problem I was getting into is still here...

If you could recheck the first question, I updated it.

I also need to get all events user has been on with event description. Thanks in advance